# Custom React debouncer hook

Tags: javascript, react.js

I'm new to React hooks and trying to learn to write custom hooks. Today I wrote a hook that I believe works as an effective debouncer of a setter function, to prevent excessive updates when data changes rapidly. I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible so as to be reusable throughout the app and by other developers on my team if they need it.

I have tested this, and it appears to work as expected. It's currently being used to prevent excessive updates from a textfield. I'm unsure of any hidden performance drains doing this might cause, and I also don't know if I've gone about doing this in a way that makes sense (or if there might be less complicated ways of accomplishing what I want.

```
// Returns a callback function that wraps the passed setter in a debouncer mechanism
// While the timer is off, the setter will be called immediately and trigger a new timer.
// While the timer is on, the value to be set is captured and used at the end of the timer period.
// Subsequent calls during the timer period will replace the captured value to be set, there is no queue.
export function useDebouncedSetter(setter: (value: any) => void, timeout = 1000) {
    const timerActive = useRef(false);
    const valueCapture = useRef(null);  
    const setterCapture = useRef(setter);  // Capture the setter value to detect if a new one is passed

    return useCallback(async (value: any) => {
        if (timerActive.current === true) {
            valueCapture.current = value;
        } else {
            setter(value);
            valueCapture.current = value;
            timerActive.current = true;
            setterCapture.current = setter;
            setTimeout(() => {
                timerActive.current = false;
                // If the last captured value is the same as the value when the timeout was started, do nothing
                // If the last captured setter is different from the current setter, do nothing
                // This later case means a new setter was passed invalidating the old one.
                if (valueCapture.current !== value && setterCapture.current === setter) {
                    setter(valueCapture.current);
                }
            }, timeout);
        }
        return () => {
            // Cleanup, set the flag to false, get rid of the last value.
            timerActive.current = false;
            valueCapture.current = null;
        }
    }, [setter, timeout]);
}
```

How best can I improve this? How can I tested its effectiveness compared to other methods, if any are feasible?